# how to force one jquery line to execute only after another has finished

Tags: jquery

I have some jquery code that's being executed just fine:

```
$("#aInfo").load("singleReturn.php?q="+encodeURIComponent(item));  
  $("#bInfo").load("doubleSelect.php");
```

both of these lines are executed at (basically) the same time; singleReturn.php takes about 3 seconds to load due to the complex code, and doubleSelect.php takes only a split second.  I'd like for doubleSelect.php to NOT load until after singleReturn.php is completely loaded.

I'm not sure of what this is called in jquery, so i wasn't sure what to search for... the things I did search for didn't give me back what I'm looking for, so my apologies if this is a duplicate question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the docs of [`load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) that would be:

```
$("#aInfo").load("singleReturn.php?q="+encodeURIComponent(item), function() {
    $("#bInfo").load("doubleSelect.php");
});
```

The word you were looking for was `callback`.

Comment: Yeah - I had to wait like 15 minutes and I was leaving work :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use $.ajax(), and then call the second page in the onComplete function for the ajax call. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/